# Getting count from joined table

Tags: mysql, database

Here's my problem: I need to get the amount of test cases and issues associated to a project that meet certain conditions (test cases that are successful, and issues that are flaws of the application), but for some reason the amount doesn't add up. I have 10 test cases in a project, of which 6 are successful; and 8 issues, of which only 4 are flaws. However, the respective results for COUNT each show 24, which makes no sense. I did notice, though, that 24 happens to be 6 times 4, but I don't see how the query would multiply them.

Anyway... Can someone help me find which part of my query is wrong? How can I get the correct result? Thanks in advance.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    p.codigo_proyecto,
    p.nombre,
    IFNULL(COUNT(iep.id_incidencia_etapa_proyecto), 0) AS cantidad_defectos,
    IFNULL(COUNT(tc.id_test_case), 0) AS test_cases_exitosos,
    CASE IFNULL(COUNT(tc.id_test_case), 0) WHEN 0 THEN 'No aplica'
    ELSE CONCAT((IFNULL(COUNT(tc.id_test_case), 0) / IFNULL(COUNT(tc.id_test_case), 0)) * 100, '%') END AS tasa_defectos
FROM proyecto p
INNER JOIN etapa_proyecto ep ON p.codigo_proyecto = ep.codigo_proyecto
INNER JOIN incidencia_etapa_proyecto iep ON ep.id_etapa_proyecto = iep.id_etapa_proyecto
INNER JOIN incidencia i ON iep.id_incidencia = i.id_incidencia
INNER JOIN test_case tc ON ep.id_etapa_proyecto = tc.id_etapa_proyecto
INNER JOIN etapa_proyecto ep_ultima ON ep_ultima.id_etapa_proyecto =
    (SELECT ep_ultima2.id_etapa_proyecto FROM etapa_proyecto ep_ultima2
    WHERE p.codigo_proyecto = ep_ultima2.codigo_proyecto ORDER BY ep_ultima2.fecha_termino_real DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE p.esta_cerrado = 1
AND i.es_defecto = 1
AND tc.resultado = 'Exitoso'
AND ep_ultima.fecha_termino_real BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-12-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought it obvious that you're not going to get the expected output from an aggregate query without a GROUP BY (which suggests you're not really in a position to evaluate any advice given here effectively).

You've not said how the states of your data are represented in the database - so I'm having to make a lot of guesses based on SQL which is clearly very wrong. And I don't speak spanish/portugese or whatever your native language is.

It looks like you are inferring that a defect exists if the primary key of the defects table is null. Primary keys cannot be null. The only way this would make any sort of sense (BTW it still won't give you the answer you're looking for) is to do a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN.

But even then a simple COUNT() will consider null cases (no record in source table) as 1 record in the output set.

Then you've got the problem that you will have the product of defects and test cases in your output - consider the case where you have no defects, but 2 tests cases (1,2) - the result of an outer joiun will be:

```
defect   test
------   ----
null     1
null     2
```

If you just count the rows, you'll get 2 defects in your output.

Taking a simpler schema, this demonstrates the 2 methods for getting the values - note that they have very different performance characteristics.

```
SELECT project.id
, dilv.defects
, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM test_cases) AS tests
FROM project
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) AS defects
    FROM defect_table
    GROUP BY project_id) AS dilv
ON project.id=dilv.project_id
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the quality of my question. I'm in a hurry to finish this thing, and I didn't sleep a lot last night, so I'm not really very sharp today. Now that I read your answer, it seems obvious. Just let me tell you that, although I'm not a veteran, I'm no amateur, either: I know a primary key can't be null, and in fact whether an issue is a defect or not is specified in a column ("is_defect") in the table "issue". Anyway, you actually did give me the help I asked for, although I guess you could have been more polite. Still, thank you. I'll fix my question when I have time.